# Language in claim:definition

Tags: claims, definitions

I am writing a claim in which I want to define an object, which is similar to (yet ever so slightly different from) many other like objects. I am doing it like this:"...designating one of said framzits within a collection of one or more of said framzits as superior to other framzits in said collection, ***such a framzit hereinafter labeled a superior framzit,*** and ..[blah, blah] .. utilizing said ***superior framzit*** to club said seal pup or seal pups to death ..." (or whatever). Is my little definition-in-line there legit, and if not, what else can I use?

Comment: a set of at least two widgets, a first one of which is the [tallest] widget . . . where the first widget is . . .

Comment: 'Your wording may also be OK if superior is a stand in for something more meaningful. Also, "one or more" in your example wording includes the case of exactly one in which case you do not have many like objects with one a little different, you just have one. If that is not the desired scope then you can use "two or more".